# Can I win a game of CivWorld as a solo nation?

Tags: civworld

I'm running into a strategy bottleneck when I'm trying to exist as a solo nation and not a conglomorate and be at all competitive overall.  If one tries to focus on keeping up in science or culture early game you end up getting extremely limited late game by having a severe population gimp due to having to overspecialize early on.

I'm wondering if anyone else has ran into this and has anyone found what would be an acceptable way to get around this for a solo nation?  (Hard to speed test these since only one game can go on at a time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are playing against reasonably competent opponents, the answer is no.

The game is designed to be played as an alliance, and significant boosts are received for doing so. If you want to play as a single player and still be competitive, the best way is to find a situation where there are 2 major powers during the early game, and join neither.

Make sure to try and keep those two powers balanced. Then, offer to join whoever will give you the best advantage. While that doesn't allow you to play solo the entire game, it lets you determine the outcome of the game single-handedly, and play a decent part of the game solo.